# Cut and Delete Row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I cut and paste a row of data in Excel the data is moved but the empty row remains.  Is there a shortcut key or option that lets me move the row without leave an empty row behind?

Comment: I know what you mean, but just to make it clearer. cut and paste does a copy and paste. and you want to copy paste and delete the original row. Maybe some macro could speed it up I don't know

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the row that you want to cut. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. Marching ants (marquee) appear around the range.

   [image]
2. Select the cell to which want to move the data.

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>+</kbd> .

   [image]

   *Note that this may only work if the source and destination ranges are along the same column.*

Comment: Ctrl+Shift++ doesn't work for me, but right click "Inset Cuts Cells" does

Comment: @chris Yep, that's another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contextual-menu.

1. Select the row you want to copy
2. Cut it (with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or menu Edit>Cut)
3. Select the row where you want you data to be pasted
4. Right-click and choose `Insert copied cells` (or anything that looks like, my Excel version is not in English)

Comment: -1 You mean Ctrl+x (cut) and "Insert Cut Cells"

Comment: this is what my answer meant and led to the right process...